# Filtering a large data frame based on column values using R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, data-science

I have a very large dataframe with almost 502493 rows and 261 columns. I want to filter it and need IDs with specific codes (codes starting with 'E'). This is how my data looks like,

| IDs | code1 | code2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C443 | E109 |
| 2 | AX31 | M223 |
| 1 | E341 | QWE1 |
| 3 | E131 | M223 |

My required output is IDs with codes starting with 'E' only.

| IDs | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | E109 |
| 1 | E341 |
| 3 | E131 |

I am trying to use the 'filter' of dplyr package but not getting the required output.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and `filter` by creating a logical vector from the first character extracted (with `substr`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("code"), 
       values_to = 'code', names_to = NULL) %>%   
   filter(substr(code, 1, 1) == "E")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    IDs code 
  <int> <chr>
1     1 E109 
2     1 E341 
3     3 E131
```

---

If the data is really big, we may do a `filter` before the `pivot_longer` to keep only rows having at least one 'E' in the column

```
df1 %>%
   filter(if_any(starts_with('code'), ~ substr(., 1, 1) == 'E')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("code"), 
       values_to = 'code', names_to = NULL) %>%   
   filter(substr(code, 1, 1) == "E")
```

---

If it is a very big data, another option is `data.table`.  Convert the data.frame to 'data.table' (`setDT`), loop across the columns of interest (`.SDcols`) with `lapply`, `replace` the elements that are not starting with "E" to `NA`, then use `fcoalesce` to get the first non-NA element for each row using `do.call`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df1)[, .(IDs, code = do.call(fcoalesce, 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, substr(x, 1, 1) != "E", 
      NA)))), .SDcols = patterns("code")])
```

-output

```
   IDs code
1:   1 E109
2:   1 E341
3:   3 E131
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(IDs = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), code1 = c("C443", "AX31", 
"E341", "E131"), code2 = c("E109", "M223", "QWE1", "M223")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```